Unable To Instantiate Servlet Class While Deploying WebApp through Tomcat using INTELLIJ IDEA
I was trying to make a servlet for webapp, In INTELLIJ IDEA. While deploying there was no error but when the servlet is called in the web, it says
"jakarta.servlet.ServletException: Error instantiating servlet class [com.servlet.AddServlet]"
I searched in project structure to see if the module is added to path but still no avail

Try writing and deploying a simple HelloWorld Servlet to get your deployment working. Only after that should you start your real programming.

Use IntelliJ’s new-project template for Jakarta EE. You will start with a properly functioning web app.

Include the entire error message when posting here.
